# ESTA denied because overstay - how to appeal?

Tags: usa, paperwork, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, overstaying

My father's ESTA was cancelled after he overstayed with 3 months due to Covid.

It was extended every 30 days because his flight was cancelled and there were no flights to Europe in that period of time, that's why they always approved the requested extensions.

When I checked his ESTA status after I received an email that it has been changed I saw his ESTA was cancelled and he should apply for a Visa.

What is the best thing to do?

He didn't do anything illegal, he just couldn't leave the country due to Covid. My father is old and I don't want him to go through the stress related with applying for a visa, ESTA was so easy and he never would stay longer than 3 months, no need for a visa which would allow him to stay for 6 months. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Honestly in this circumstance, going for a Visa interview isn't going to be a problem, in my opinion. The good part of US Visa interviews are that they are in person, so if he explains why he couldn't leave before the expiry of his status it's quite likely that it will be granted.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119403/discussion-on-question-by-kati-elekes-esta-denied-because-overstay-covid).

Comment: And if he asks they will probably give him a ten year visa.

Comment: @DJClayworth [unless he's Australian, in which case it will be five years](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/Visa-Reciprocity-and-Civil-Documents-by-Country/australia.html).

Answer (score 37):

If you're sure he left within a 30-day grace period (i.e. it didn't expire), then e-mail the CBP at esta@cbp.dhs.gov **and** tcc@cbp.dhs.gov, explaining the situation in clear detail and attaching ALL supporting documentation, including his passport. Politely request that they revoke your father's VWP ineligibility on the basis that he was given *satisfactory departure* three times (again, attach proof) and left within the granted period